# How can I write the following mongodb query in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, record

How can I write the following query using Spring Data MongoDB?

```
db.collection.find().sort({$natural: -1}).limit(5)
```

This query looks for the most recent 5 documents from the collection.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us what you have tried and create a [mre]. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` method from Spring Data MongoDB repository or template with the following `Query`

```
new Query().with(Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "$natural")).limit(5);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex
Just want to ask one more question. I tried the above approach -- Query ans =  new Query().with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "$natural")).limit(2);
           List<classname> answer = (List<classname>) repoOfCollectionNames.findAll((Pageable)ans);

Comment: But still it showed me error that can not caste query into pageable

Comment: You can't cast it like this and not sure why you need pagination for this query. Look at `MongoTemplate` instead.

Comment: Okay got it. My bad I'm new to this ..was using findAll method of mongoRepo
Thanks a ton.